# Trouble logging into my hp stream 6

Tags: windows-10, login

This computer not only insists I sign in to a Microsoft email at the login screen, but it insists I sign in to a certain Microsoft email that I simply can't. So I try to click back in order to change the login-email, and when I do, I am brought back to the initial sign-in screen and then asked again to sign in to the same email, like it's locked in for some reason, effectively bricking this thing. Help.

Comment: Log into the built-in Administrator account and create a new local account that isn’t linked to a Microsoft Account.  Alternatively, log into the existing account, and disconnect the Microsoft Account.  Yes; That will require you to log into the Microsoft Account that’s currently linked to the account.  Either way the built-in Administrator account solves your issue

Comment: Ramhound, if logging in as anything but this email were an option, this post wouldn't exist. Or are you aware of some keyboard shortcut to enter admin, that.you for whatever reason didn't share. Are other questions on here really so obvious?

Comment: NVM. Solution is resetting the pc by shift-clicking power button.

Comment: I provided instructions to enable the built-in Administrator account which would have allowed you to create a local account that wasn’t connected to a Microsoft Account.  Sounds like you should disconnect the Microsoft Account now that you have access to your account